# Перепрыгивание в верх страницы при ajax-запросе

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток, господа.

```
// код который передает id в pagr.php
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").click(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                url: "pagr.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {id: id},
                success: function(text) {
                    $("#text").html(text);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

// ссылки для Ajax
<a href="#" id="1">ссылка 1</a>
<a href="#" id="2">ссылка 2</a>

// вот сюда вставляются данные полученные от Ajax
<div id="text">
текст 0
</div>

// страница pagr.php
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
```

Собственно все примитивно и просто. Нажимаем кнопку, происходит передача id ссылки странице pagr.php, та отображает что нужно. Все работает прекрасно. Перезагрузки страницы нету.

Если страница в высоту больше чем 1 экран, то при нажатии на кнопку, сам скрипт работает, но при этом идет перепрыгивание в верх страницы. Подскажите как это исправить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Измените обработчик клика следующем образом:

```
    $("a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            ...
    }
```

Подробнее о preventDefault можно почитать [здесь](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

Comment: работает. ставлю акцепт!

Answer (score 2):

Или:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
   /*...*/
   return false;
}
```

Comment: сработало. в теме 3 ответа, которые сработали. жаль что принять можно только 1

Answer (score 0):

Уберите `href="#"` с ссылок и просто поставьте `{cursor:pointer}`.

Comment: Т.е. так:

    <a style="{cursor:pointer}" id="1">ссылка 1</a>

\- сработало. Спасибо! ROOT, а можно это сделать в качестве ответа, а не комментария? Я хочу влепить акцепт.

Answer (score 0):

В ссылке вместо # необходимо указать, к примеру, `javascript:void(0)`.