# JS скрипт передающий данные методом POST в IE8

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток господа

Пользуюсь одной конструкцией, уже оч. давно

```
// html
<a style="{cursor:pointer}" id="123">Link1</a>

// чуть ниже блок в котором меняется содержимое в зависимости от переданного id
<div id="text"></div>

// js код. чуть ниже на этой же странице
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(id != 'goTop'){
        $.ajax({
        url: "page.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(text) {
        $("#text").html(text);
        }
    });
    }
});
});
</script>

// страница page.php принимает данные, переваривает, и если нужно, то выводит результат в блок div на странице <div id="text"></div>
```

Данные странице передаются, но в IE 8 в блоке  не обновляются. Может ли кто подсказать, как дописать этот код, что бы работало и на IE 8 тоже ?

p.s. обсуждал немного другую модернизацию этого же скрипта, все устраивает, только не в IE . [один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/150011/javascript-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-js-%D0%B8-ajax) , [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/141233/php-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5)

p.p.s. т.к. кол-во комментариев ограничено, я кое что уточню

id - пробовал писать не число. не помогает

```
<div id="text"><? //инклюдим page.php  ?></div>
```

в самой page.php просто вывод, если есть переданный пост, выводим его. все предельно просто.

Comment: Каких-то явных ошибок нет, если вы всё показали, как есть. Должно работать. Пока только один вопрос созрел - а как вы отменяете событие клика по ссылке?

Comment: обычно для спользования чисел в id я добавляю префикс. Очень удобно при правке данных связаных с БД

Comment: @mixalef, Баг где-то в другом месте. Давайте чуть подробней и проверить даже мелочи. Просмотрите **сгенерированный** код страницы. Нет ли дублирующих id у элементов? Какая версия библиотеки? <div id="text"> добавляется динамически или статичный?

P.S. Сразу же попробуйте следующее: найдите ближайший, статичный родительский элемент у ссылки (для теста, даже *body* или *document* подойдет). Самой ссылке - какой-нить класс "your_class" И зменяете код так:

    $("parent_block_selector").on('click','a.your_class',function() {
       // тут - как и было
    }

Comment: А если вместо 
    $("#text").html(text);
вставить
    alert(text);
что происходит?

Comment: опера при алерте выдала код страницы (который нужен). IE выдал "undefinded". сейчас попробую скопировать код на тестовый хостинг

Comment: Ща уже места под коменты закончаться, поэтому я свои старые буду периодически удалять.

**Важно**. Я обратил внимание, что вы не указываете **dataType** в опциях ajax. А в каком виде получаете ответ от сервера?

Comment: добавив код $("parent_block_selector")... все сработало. нужно это в ответ поместить. вот про то как переделать скрипт добавив dataType - не понял. Буду заниматься гуглением

Comment: @mixalef, Уже не мог оставлять комментарии, поэтому перенес предыдущий в ответ. По поводу dataType - [смотрите тут](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. заменить строку:

   ```
   $("a").click(function() {
   // на следующую
   $("parent_block_selector").on('click','a.your_class',function() {

   Вместо **parent_block_selector** - селектор родительского блока для ссылки.
   ```
2. Минусуют и банят, когда ссылки не по теме, когда они ведут на непонятные ресурсы, когда это спам и т.д. ))  Выкладывайте только относяшееся к делу в инет и ссылку сюда в комментарии.

**UPD** По поводу dataType - [смотрите тут](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)